# Right Justify A column In Oracle table

Tags: oracle10g

Hi Guys i am Looking for a way to update a Clumn that is left Justified to Right Justified in Oracle 10g. The Field is a Varchar2 field I had thought of something Like :

```
update tbaadm.dst set DD_NUM = Ltrim(DD_NUM);
```

But this will trim Only the white spaces and will not Actaully Right Justify the data.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather unusual requirement - usually when someone asks for something to be justified right or left, they are referring to how the data should *appear when displayed* (e.g. on the screen or in a report) - not in the actual data itself.

Most screen design and reporting tools (e.g. Oracle Reports) allow you to set the Justification option on any item.

But, if updating the original data is *really* what you need to do - you can use LPAD:

```
update tbaadm.dst set DD_NUM = lpad(DD_NUM, 30);
```

Replace `30` with the maximum size of the column. But I sincerely doubt this is really what you should do.